# Sum Python Pandas Groupby() row with another Groupby() Value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am still very new to python and Pandas, but I have created three groupby dataframes to sort my spreadsheet and return totals for each type using:

```
a = (df.groupby('Type')['Income'].sum())
b = (df.groupby('Type')['Value'].sum())
c = (df.groupby('Type')['Price'].sum())
```

for each of these groups they return something like:

```
Type
Object 1           0.00
Object 2           -2.50
Object 3           -30.00
Object 4            1.30
Object 5           -20.10
Object 6           -7.60
Object 7           -8.09
```

How would I go about now summing together for example 'Object 6' from each groupby data set? For example (group a, object 6) + (group b, object 6)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the sum result of: (group a, object 6) + (group b, object 6), you can use:

```
a['Object 6'] + b['Object 6']
```

For now `a` and `b` are Pandas Series after the `.groupby()` and `.sum()` on the respective columns.  The original `Type` columns become row index of the series, you can access the Series elements by subscripting with the index values (i.e. `Object 6` in this case).

Comment: @Asherzi  Great that it works for you.  Remember to accept the solution by putting a tick beside my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To sum object 6:

```
a['6'] + b['6'] + c['6']
```

But you can do all of them at once:

```
a + b + c
```

If the index name is not the same, you may have to rename it so that it's the same for a, b and c:

```
new_index = ['Object 1', 'Object 2', 'Object 3', ...]
a.index = new_index
b.index = new_index
c.index = new_index
```

This is considering that the three of them are "Series". If it is not the case, I'll fix this.